# Is it possible to pre-warm the app?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

When you run `dotnet run` on your MVC6 application it takes long time on first request but then it's obviously works fine. I've tried to find answers in google but it's impossible because all I get is articles about IIS which I am not using at all. In fact I run the code on Ubuntu.

Is it possible to pre-warm the `dotnet run` so the first request will be as fast as the second?

Comment: What about making first request yourself, right after restart, with curl?

Comment: My current deployment script actually is doing that but it's not what I want.

Comment: there are two reasons why your application is slow when using dotnet run - 1) application compilation 2) view compilation. `dotnet run` always checks if the application changed and if it did it will recompile it (by default for each target framework). If this is for running application in production don't use dotnet run but publish the application and run it directly. If this is during development make sure that you only compile for the framework you run the application. Views are compiled at runtime. It might be possible to precompile views but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @Pawel: Precompilation has been removed from RC2 https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3917

Comment: What you could do is using the remaining execution of your `Main` to do a request to your kestrel instance.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

1. Use the Release build so the code is optimised for production use rather than debugging (`dotnet run --configuration Release`)
2. Initiate the first connection yourself, therefore all subsequent requests from your clients are "warm"
3. Compile using the `--native` flag, then host the results to further benefit from performance optimisation

Lastly (and this point is pure speculation), potentially look at running your published web site in a production web server host (e.g. Apache or IIS) rather than from the dotnet cli. This *may* provide performance enhancements, but would certainly offer "warming" features that aren't present in the CLI (I know IIS has an Always-On option).

Comment: If I run it in Apache or Nginx it will be just a reverse-proxy so it will not be any different from CLI. Or .NET already has cgi implementation?

Comment: Correct. It's more the case that these servers are more feature rich, like iis has always on mode. Also, you could run a server farm with multiple instances proxy'ed, then upgrade them individually and only enable them when they are warm.